# Reassignment to val error when var member of base class in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

Scala throws "reassignment to val" error for the following code.

```
abstract case class Gun(var bulletCount:Int)
class Pistol(bulletCount:Int) extends Gun(bulletCount){
def fire() { bulletCount=bulletCount-1 }
}
```

Anything I missed here?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you should consider `case class` as final, and not extend them.

Second, do not use `var` with `case class`, you should rather create a copy of a `case class` to get one of its field changed.

Third, if you want a common type, you can use a base trait.

All in one, here's what it could look like:

```
sealed trait Gun {
  def bulletCount: Int
}

case class Pistol(bulletCount: Int) extends Gun {
  def fire(): Pistol = copy(bulletCount=bulletCount)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `bulletCount` field generated by `Pistol` primary constructor parameter. To set base class variable, you need to directly call field using `super`:

```
class Pistol(bulletCount: Int) extends Gun(bulletCount) {

  def fire(): Unit = {
    super.bulletCount = super.bulletCount - 1 
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can label parameter-generated field with `override var`:

```
class Pistol(override var bulletCount: Int) extends Gun(bulletCount) {

  def fire(): Unit = {
    bulletCount = bulletCount - 1
  }
}
```

On a side note, as Frederic A. suggested in his answer, you should avoid inheriting case classes. They are syntactic sugar, and code generation don't work over inheritance - you'll need to implement all the fancy stuff like `apply` or `unapply` methods in companion class all by yourself. Scala compiler team tried to support case class to case class inheritance, but discovered that it breaks structural equality and lots of other things.